# Enabling Apache

Tags: apache, php

I cannot find the web sharing option in the system preferences under "Sharing"(where the web sharing is supposed to be). I am using Mac Os x 10.9.4

Answer (score 2):

*Warning: The normal user will be happy with Server.app*

Apache is still available, but the user interface is gone. If you are comfortable configuring Apache the traditional way via config files, you can activate it by running `sudo apachectl start` from the shell. You find the config files in `/etc/apache2`. Be prepared to restore your configuration on OS updates.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `sudo apachectl start`.

`apachectl` is a shell script and `sudo apachectl start` runs `launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` as root, which modifies `/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist` to enable apache permanently.

To make `localhost/~yourusername` point to `~/Sites/`, run

```
echo '<Directory "/Users/'$USER'/Sites/">
  Options Indexes Multiviews
  AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>'|sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/users/$USER.conf
```

and run `sudo apachectl restart`.

To enable PHP, uncomment

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and run `sudo apachectl restart`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not comfortable with the command line methods,  you might consider installing MAMP, which offers a convenient GUI for starting, stopping and basic configuration: http://www.mamp.info/en/